# MYSQL: need help for rapidly growing table and decreasing speed (4mio rows)

Tags: mysql, node.js, optimization, indexing, database-partitioning

I'm facing some issues with a rapidly growing table at increasing speed (currently 4mio rows, 300k inserts a day). I hope I can get some ideas and advices here to improve my setup and squeeze the last bit out of my box, before it takes down my website in near future.

The setup:

```
    Intel i7 720 
    8GB RAM
    2x750GB SATA RAID 0
    CentOS
    MySQL 5.5.10
    Node.js + node-lib_mysql-client
```

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `canvas` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`x1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`y1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`x2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`y2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`c` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
`s` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`m` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`r` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`x1`,`y1`) KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1024,
KEY `x1` (`x1`,`y1`) KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1024,
KEY `x2` (`x2`,`y2`) KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1024
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH ( (
(
x1 MOD 10000
)
) + y1 MOD 10000)
PARTITIONS 10 */ AUTO_INCREMENT=13168904 ;
```

The query:

```
SELECT x1,y1,x2,y2,s,c,r,m FROM canvas
WHERE 1 AND ((
 x1 >= 0
 AND x1 <= 400
 AND y1 >= 0
 AND y1 <= 400
 ) OR ( 
 x2 >= 0
 AND x2 <= 400
 AND y2 >= 0
 AND y2 <= 400
 ) )
  ORDER BY id desc
```

That's the only query I'm executing, except for the fact that the values for x1,y1,x2 and y2 change per query. It's a 2D canvas and each row represents a line on the canvas. Guess it's also important to know that the maximum range selected for 1 field is never bigger than 1200 (pixels).
A few weeks ago I upgraded to MySQL 5.5.10 and started using partitions. The 'x1 % 10000' hashw as my first and unaware approach to get into the partition topic. It already gave me a decent boost in SELECT speed, but I'm sure there's still room for optimizations.

Oh, and before you ask... I'm aware of the fact that I'm using a MyISAM table. A friend of mine suggested innoDB, but tried it already and the result was a 2 times bigger table and a big drop in SELECT performance. I don't need no fancy transactions and stuff.... all I need is the best possible SELECT performance and a decent performance with INSERTs.

What would you change? Could I perhaps tweak my indexes somehow? Does my partion setup make any sense at all? Should I perhaps increase the number of partition files?

All suggestions are welcome... I also discussed a local replication into a memory table with a friend, but I'm sure it's only a matter of time until the table size would exeed my RAM and a swapping box is a fairly ugly thing to see.

When you think about my issue please keep in mind that it's growing rapidly and unpredictably. In case it goes viral somewhere for some reason, I expect to see more than 1mio INSERTS a day.

Thank you for reading and thinking about it. :)

EDIT: The requested EXPLAIN result

```
select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
SIMPLE  canvas  index_merge     x1,x2   x1,x2   8,8     NULL    133532  Using sort_union(x1,x2); Using where; Using fileso...
```

EDIT2: The requested my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_file_format = Barracuda

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 100M

# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html
;performance_schema


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

The innoDB values are for my innoDB try... guess they are not necessary anymore. The sever runs 4 other Websites as well, but they are rather small and not really worth to mention. I'm gonna move this project to a dedicated box soon anyways. Your ideas can be radical - I don't mind experiments.

**EDIT3 - BENCHMARKS WITH INDEXES**

Ok guys... I've made some benchmarks with different indexes and the results are pretty good so far. For this benchmark I've was selecting all rows within a box of 2000x2000 pixels.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE x1,y1,x2,y2,s,c FROM canvas_test WHERE 1 AND (( x1 BETWEEN -6728 AND -4328 AND y1 BETWEEN -6040 AND -4440 ) OR (  x2 BETWEEN -6728 AND -4328 AND y2 BETWEEN -6040 AND -4440 ) )  ORDER BY id asc
```

Using the table/index definition I've posted above the avarage query time was: *1740ms*

Then I dropped all indexes, except for the primary key -> *1900ms*

added one index for x1 -> 1800ms

added one index for y1 -> 1700ms

added one index for x2 -> 1500ms

added one index for y2 -> 900ms!

That's quite astonishing so far... for some reason I was thinking making combined indexes for x1/y1 and x2/y2 would make sense somehow, but actually it looks like I was wrong.

EXPLAIN now returns this:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  canvas_test     index_merge     x1,y1,x2,y2     y1,y2   4,4     NULL    263998  Using sort_union(y1,y2); Using where; Using fileso..
```

Now I'm wondering why it's using y1/y2 as keys and not all four?

However, I'm still looking for more ideas and advices, especially regarding partitions and proper hashing.

Comment: can you add the EXPLAIN results of this query? Just type EXPLAIN <your_query>

Comment: Have you looked at using a spatial index instead? joining two ranges can be pretty expensive depending upon the distribution of your values (i.e. their may be a pile of rows with values of x1 between 0 and 400 and another pile of rows with values of y1 between 0 and 400 even if there are only a few rows that fit both critera -- at some point that just gets expensive with a btree index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How much memory is your server currently utilizing?
2. Is this the only database/table on the server?
3. Are you using MyISAM exclusively?

MyISAM is okay to use, so long as you're not updating your rows.  When you update a row on a MyISAM table MySQL locks the entire table, blocking any SELECTs and INSERTS from executing until the UPDATE is complete.  UPDATE has precedence over SELECT, so if you have a lot of UPDATEs running, your SELECTS will wait until they're all complete before they return any rows.

If that is okay with you, then move to your server configuration.  What does your my.cnf file look like?  You'll want to optimize this file to maximize the amount of memory you can use for indexes.  If these SELECTs are slowing down, it's because your table indexes are not fitting in memory.  If MySQL can't fit your table indexes into memory, then it has to go to disk and do a table scan to fetch your data.  This will *kill* performance.

**EDIT 5/18/2011 9:30PM EST**

After looking at your my.cnf, I notice you have *zero* MyISAM optimizations in place.  Your starting place is going to be the `key_buffer_size` variable.  This variable is, as a rule of thumb, set somewhere between 25% and 50% of the total available memory on your system.  Your system has 8GB memory available, so somewhere around 3GB is a minimum starting point, I'd say.  However, you can estimate how much you will need and optimize it as needed if you know you have control over the other variables on the system.

What you should do is cd to your mysql data dir (typically `/var/lib/mysql`) which is where all your data files are located.  A quick way to tell how much index data you have is to do

```
 sudo du -hc `find . -type f -name "*.MYI"
```

This command will look at the size of all your MyISAM Index files and tell you their total size.  If you have *enough* memory, you want to make your `key_buffer_size` in your my.cnf BIGGER than the total size of all your MYI files.  This will ensure that your MyISAM indexes are in memory, so MySQL won't have to hit the disk for the index data.

A quick note, don't go increasing your `key_buffer_size` willy nilly.  This is just one area of MySQL that needs memory, there are other moving parts that you need to balance memory usage with.  MySQL connections take up memory, and different table engines use different memory pools for their indexes, and MySQL uses other bits of memory for different things.  If you run out of memory because you set the `key_buffer_size` too large, your server could start paging (using virtual memory, which will KILL performance even MORE) or worse, crash.  Start with smaller values if you're unsure, check your memory usage, and increase it until you're satisfied with the performance, and your server isn't crashing.

Comment: TOP displays Mem:   8166420k total,  7787212k used,   379208k free. I've added the mysql config to my question. thank you

Comment: top doesn't help so much, because it doesn't tell you what is in use and what is cached. try using `free -m` to get a more telling count

Comment: free -m basically displays the same values as top does. I have about 4500MB cached - so these MegaBytes are theoretically available as far as I understand these values. However, thank you for your detailed explanation. All my MyISAM index files together have about 235MB. I've set the key_buffer_size to 1GB (ok...it's a bit willy nilly ;) sorry). Haven't had the opportunity to bench it properly, but I'll update my question as soon as I can come up with some more details. Thanks again Jim! Looking forward for more input ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd modify the SELECT as

```
SELECT x1,y1,x2,y2,s,c,r,m FROM canvas
WHERE 
  x1 BETWEEN 0 AND 400 AND y1 BETWEEN 0 AND 400 OR
  x2 BETWEEN 0 AND 400 AND y2 BETWEEN 0 AND 400
ORDER BY id desc
```

And also be sure to have an index on that expression:

```
CREATE INDEX canvas400 ON canvas(
  x1 BETWEEN 0 AND 400 AND y1 BETWEEN 0 AND 400 OR
  x2 BETWEEN 0 AND 400 AND y2 BETWEEN 0 AND 400
)
```

Comment: Erm, but you index is only for a box of 400x400? The entire canvas is about 4mio x 4mio pixels atm. The between syntax however is neat indeed, will change my syntax accordingly.

Comment: I didn't see that size was variable.  Is the size truly variable or are there just a few sizes that you'll be searching for?

Comment: The queries select 2D boxes, usually with a size of 400x400 boxes. The entire canvas has 4mio x 4mio pixels. So the values for x1/y1 or x2/y2 change on almost every query :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your data, but if you're looking for a record that's storing a 400 x 400 pixel portion of the canvas then I think your query should be `SELECT x1,y1,x2,y2,s,c,r,m FROM canvas
WHERE x2 - x1 = 400 AND y2 - y1 = 400`. If that's correct then you'd want two indexes: `x2 - x1` and `y2 - y1`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that MySQL will only use one index per table per query. Your SELECT query won't be able to make use of both of your indexes in the same query - it will use one or the other. You might find that it's more efficient to UNION two SELECT queries together so that each one can use the appropriate index, eg:

```
SELECT x1,y1,x2,y2,s,c,r,m FROM canvas
WHERE 
 x1 >= 0
 AND x1 <= 400
 AND y1 >= 0
 AND y1 <= 400
UNION
SELECT x1,y1,x2,y2,s,c,r,m FROM canvas
WHERE
 x2 >= 0
 AND x2 <= 400
 AND y2 >= 0
 AND y2 <= 400
;
```

or you could use BETWEEN like one of the other replies suggested, eg:

```
SELECT x1,y1,x2,y2,s,c,r,m FROM canvas
WHERE x1 BETWEEN 0 AND 400 AND y1 BETWEEN 0 AND 400
UNION
SELECT x1,y1,x2,y2,s,c,r,m FROM canvas
WHERE x2 BETWEEN 0 AND 400 AND y2 BETWEEN 0 AND 400
;
```

It's a while since I've used a UNION so I'm not sure where you'd put your ORDER BY clause but you can experiment with that.

As one of the other replies mentioned, use EXPLAIN to see how many rows MySQL will have to consider in order to satisfy the queries.

It might also be worth looking at an RTREE index, though I've not played with those myself.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of speeds are you getting? Since you don't need any relational stuff you should consider moving your data to [Redis](http://redis.io/), it should easily do +100k inserts or reads/sec on your machine.

Comment: Well, my queries take about 0.17-0.3seconds (when system is idle), but adds up under load. I already had Redis in mind, but wasn't sure if it's worth to give it a try. Before MySQL I was on Mongo...the performance was bad and with spatial indexes (which sounded fancy and the right thing todo) even worse. MySQL is doing surprisingly well so far, besides my concerns of the rapidly growing data, thus the reduced SELECT performance.